# Minecraft crossplay between iPad and switch

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I recently got Minecraft on my iPad in order to play with a friend who owns a copy of the game on Switch. We both run the same version of Minecraft but whenever we try to join each others world we get an error message saying "unable to join world." Could someone assist with fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [article](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/article/better-together-nintendo-switch) on minecraft.net you both of you need to have a Microsoft account to crossplay with non-Nintendo devices.

Comment: Yes we both do that's why it's strange as to why it is not working